# incomplete attachment when using direct state access functions

Tags: opengl, texture2d

I am trying to replace my old OpenGL functions with its Direct State Access versions.

I replaced

```
glBindTexture(m_target, m_name);
glTexStorage2D(m_target, 1, m_format, m_width, m_height);
glBindTexture(m_target, 0);
```

with

```
glTextureStorage2D(m_name, 1, m_format, m_width, m_height);
```

but now I get an "incomplete attachment" error with my fbo.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, if I want to use direct state access, I also have to replace

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_name);
```

with

```
glCreateTextures(m_target, 1, &m_name);
```

so that m_name will be conntected to m_target from now on.